# PickList lose value

Tags: primefaces, picklist

I have a simple persistent object (Hibernate, if it makes any different):

```
@Entity
Class ObjectA

{
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private String description;
    private List<ObjectA> children = new LinkedList<>();

    ...
    ...
    ...
    public org.primefaces.model.DualListModel<ObjectA> getDualList() {
        org.primefaces.model.DualListModel<ObjectA> l = new org.primefaces.model.DualListModel<>();
        l.setSource(this.children);
        l.setTarget(database.getAllChildren()); // performs database query to retrieve all objectA that are not corrently linked to any objectA.
        ...
        return l;
    }

    public setDualList(org.primefaces.model.DualListModel<ObjectA> l) {
        this.children = l.getSource();
        ...
    }

}
```

The PrimeFaces code looks like (relevant snippet):

```
...
<p:dataTable id="table" value="#{managedBeanA.getAllObjects}" var="iterator" paginator="true" rows="10" >
    ... 
    ...
    <p:rowExpansion>
        <p:pickList value="#{iterator.dualList}" var="l" itemLabel="#{l.name}" itemValue="#{requirement.id}">
            <f:facet name="sourceCaption">Linked Children</f:facet> 
            <f:facet name="targetCaption">Unlinked Children</f:facet>
            <p:ajax event="transfer" listener="#{managedBeanA.handleTransfer(iterator)}"/>
        </p:pickList>
    </p:rowExpansion>
</p:dataTable>
```

What managedBeanA.handleTransfer does is simply persist the passed object.

Everything seems to work lovely, I can expand the row and getDualList is called. When I expand another row, another getDualList is called - all as expected.

When I move items from source to target, managedBeanA.handleTransfer is called and the relevant object is persisted in the database.

HOWEVER, and here is the question, when the table is updated - either form submit or ajax, I can see that setDualList is called for EVERY item in the p:dataTable with EMPTY getSource which, in essence, break all the links previously persisted (i.e. this.children = null). The previously linked ObjectA objects are still in database but they are no longer linked...

Any ideas what is going on?

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution to the problem. It is probably only a workaround as I am not sure what the problem actually is - in the setDualList method, I have added the following line:

```
if (l.getSource().isEmpty() && l.getTarget().isEmpty()) return;
```

which solves all my problems (as the symptom of the issues is that the setter is called with no values).